# Maximum Geojson files permitted?

Tags: mapbox

So far I load 3 Geojson files on my Mapbox map. 
When I try to load a forth one it does not work.
Is 3 the limit for thos kind of files?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it any fourth one or have you possibly hit your limit in the number of features?

Comment: Until now, I load three geojson (map.geojson, map2.geojson, map3.geojson) with L.mapbox.featureLayer(). If I try to load map.geojson4 the same way it does not work. Total size for the 3 files is than 45 Ko. Is there a limit when you load with mapbax.js?

Comment: The only limit is your browser since it downloads the data. Can you  provide your code and samples of the failing GeoJSON file?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I had a wrong syntax in my code. Thanks for your time.